# SP Survey - Disable the export to spreadsheet action

Tags: list, excel, survey, spreadsheet

After seeing many posts concerning permission levels (untick client integration features use), i'm still unable to disable export to spreadsheet option from the action menu on a Survey.

Here is the context:
- Recurrent Survey to gather team members votes (OK)
- Team members must NOT see other team members votes (OK via OOTB options but NOK via export to spreasheet, because you can see all the results)
- The responsible of the team shall be able to see individual votes (OK via a linked Excel query)

Does anyone faced this issue or have a solution?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to hide the entire list actions menu using JavaScript and JQuery as I didn't want to expose the other available list actions (*View RSS Feed* and *Alert Me*) to our users either.

I simply inserted a script editor webpart into the "Overview" (overview.aspx), "All Responses" (AllItems.aspx) and "Graphical Summary" (summary.aspx) pages of the survey. That script editor webpart contained the following code:

```
<script src="*/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>    
<script src="*/hidelistactionsmenu.js"></script>
```

The file hidelistactionsmenu.js contained the following code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("table.ms-menutoolbar tr td.ms-toolbar").has("span[id*='ListActionsMenu_t']").hide(); // hides the table cell that contains the button that opens the list actions menu
        $("table.ms-menutoolbar tr td.ms-separator:first").hide(); // hides the duplicate separator between the buttons
    });
```

The location of the two files (*jquery-3.1.1.min.js* and *hidelistactionsmenu.js*) has to be modified accordingly. Obviously, ***** is just a placeholder for the path.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom permission level

https://serverfault.com/questions/73677/disable-export-to-spreadsheet-in-sharepoint-custom-list

or you can hide the export button using Sharepoint Designer and Javascript

https://www.codeproject.com/questions/490289/removeplustheplus-export-plusactionplustoplusc

Comment: Hello Idryl, Thank you for the answer. unfortunately managing permission level is not sufficient to disable export function on a Survey, and I have no way to use SharePoint Designer. I'll try to bypass this issue via using a custom list.